# Laravel get nested relationship from polymorphic table

Tags: laravel, mongodb, polymorphic-associations

I want to get nested relationship data from polymorphic table, I'm using [MongoDB](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) as database in my laravel app so you might notice that i don't use pivot table between `movies` and `genres` table for many to many relationship given the example below.

So what I want to achieve is to get the nested data like `frontends > genres > movies` all in one result.

let's say I have polymorphic `frontends` table, looks like this

```
frontends
  id - integer
  position - integer
  frontable_id - integer
  frontable_type - string
```

```
genres
  id - integer
  name - string
  movie_ids - array[]
```

```
movies
  id - integer
  title - string
  genre_ids - array[]
```

This is the model I have set

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class Frontend extends Model
{
    public function frontable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'frontable_type_api', 'frontable_id');
    }
}

class Genre extends Model
{

    public function movies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Movie::class, null, 'genre_ids', 'movie_ids');
    }
}

class Movie extends Model
{
    public function genres()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class, null, 'movie_ids', 'category_ids');
    }
}
```

What i have tried is to get the `frontend` table first and then its `frontable_id` relationship, not until the `movies` table

```
$frontends = Frontend::with('frontable.movies')->orderBy('position')->get();

return $frontends;
```

The relation `movies` has been declared in related model, but it won't get the `movies` data

Comment: first thing that I'm looking is your schema, movies and genres are in relationship but what about frontends? you're not creating any relationship with this table not saving reference id in movies or genre. also please share your model relationships how you're declaring?

Comment: I have edited my question regarding the model, please take a look again.